# Function takes array of expected size, signalizing that to user

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

Is it legitimate to declare a function as

```
void f (T arr[10]); // T is built-in type or class
```

To signalize the user that it expects an array of size 10? Or is it bad style?

I know that passing arrays is always handled over pointers, but it would be nice to let the user of a function know -only by taking a look to the declaration-, that the passed array must have a specified size without that the user has to read the whole documentation of the function.

Would be

```
void f (T arr[10] = 0)
{
    if (!arr)
        // do stuff without array
    else
        // do stuff with array
}
```

also ok? `f()` usable also without passing array (default argument `0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really expect only C style arrays of 10 elements,

```
void f( int (&array)[10] );
```

will enforce this; any attempt to pass anything but a `int [10]`
will fail to compile.

The problems with this are:

- If the caller has received the array as a parameter himself,
  and he hasn't followed this convention, he can't call you.  You
  cannot call this function with a pointer.
- If the caller has a larger array, and only wants you to access
  a 10 element sub-array, he can't call you.

Depending on the context, these may or may not be real problems.

Regarding your second, unrelated question:

```
void f( int arr[10] );
```

is exactly the same as:

```
void f( int* arr );
```

And it can be provided with the same default arguments.

Comment: Ok, good points. I edited my question, that the expected arrays can be also of `class type` (still called C style arrays?!), but I think the answer is the same. What concerns your mentioned problems: when I want to accept also pointers or subarrays, I could only use my solution to tell the user that an array of **minimum** 10 elements is expected. After all, is it good style?

Comment: @mb84 It's a question of style.  The `int arr[10]` is final just comments; the value `10` is ignored by the compiler.  Some people argue that it is useful anyway, as documentation. Others would argue that it is misleading, since the parameter type isn't an array.  In the end, my solution has been to not use C style arrays, so the question doesn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a single-dimension array, the following declarations are equivalent:

```
void f(int arr[10]);
void f(int* arr);
```

If indeed the function always expects an array of 10 elements, then the first declaration is a good style.

Please note, however, that it will not prevent run-time errors when accessing elements beyond `arr[9]`.

In the case of a multiple-dimension array, the following declarations are **not** equivalent:

```
void f(int arr[][10]);
void f(int** arr);
```

The first one actually tells the compiler how to "index the array".

So it's not only a good style, but also essential for your code to work correctly.

Comment: Yes, my question is only about the first dimension of whatever array. (`int arr[10][10] == int arr[][10] == int (*arr)[10]`, while `int *arr[10] == int *arr[] == int **arr`)

Comment: And maybe it could also be extended to "... always expects an array of **minimum** 10 elements ..."? Telling the user this wouldn't be possible in an other way (like suggested by James Kanze).

Answer (score 0):

It simply treats `arr` as a pointer. Take a look at the code below:

```
void f (int arr[10])
{
    cout<<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //prints 1
}


main()
{
    int arr[20];

    cout<<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //prints 20

    f(arr);
}
```

For the second part, yes. Then the pointer to `int`( that is `arr` ) will be `NULL` if no argument is passed.

Comment: This depends on architecture. A pointer is not always as big as an int. But I know this, the question is more about style.

Comment: Where did you get the notion that a pointer is always as big as an int?

Comment: I said it is *not*: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) == 1` doesn't have to hold for all pointers `type *arr`, e.g. `char *arr`. But I think you meant the `prints 1` only as example on what's happening on your machine.

Comment: @mb84 Yeah, of course it is architecture dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad style. First, it does not really check the size of a passing array (you can pass `int[20]` or even `int*` into this function. Second, it can lead to hidden mistakes like this:

```
void f(int arr[10])
{
    int other_array[10];

    assert(sizeof(arr) == sizeof(other_arr)); // <- actually, the size is different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
void f (int arr[10]);
```

might seem to declare a function that takes an array of 10 `int`s by value, however it is nothing but:

```
void f (int *arr);
```

i.e. it's a silent killer that might easily lead to ***undefined behavior*** just like the following example that tries to access memory out of the array's bounds:

```
#include <iostream>

void f (int arr[10]) {
    arr[4] = 7;
}

int main() {
    int a[2] = {1,2};
    f(a);
}
```

Taking C-style array by pointer or referrence might be more straightforward:

```
void f (int (&arr)[10]);
void f (int (*arr)[10]);
```

and also less error-prone since compiler is going to complain (regarding previous example):

> invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int (&)[10]’ from expression of type ‘int [2]’

or in case of trying to initialize a pointer with `&a`:

> cannot convert ‘int (*)[2]’ to ‘int (*)[10]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void f(int (*)[10])’

---

But the most reasonable solution that I see here is to avoid using C-style arrays completely and using ***STL containers*** instead. If the size is fixed and you have C++11 support, you might consider using `std::array<int, 10>`, otherwise use `std::vector` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void f (std::vector<int> &vec) {
    vec[4] = 7;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(10,0);
    f(vec);
    std::cout << vec[4];
}
```